# How to implement Display while respecting width, fill and alignment?

Tags: rust

I have a custom wrapper type `Length` for which I want to implement the `Display` trait. I also want it to respect the width, fill and alignment rules, which doesn't happen by default:

```
use std::fmt;

struct Length(f64);

impl fmt::Display for Length {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:.1} m", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let l = Length(1.0);
    assert_eq!(format!("{}", l),    "1.0 m");       // Passes
    assert_eq!(format!("{:10}", l), "1.0 m     ");  // Fails: padding is not added
    assert_eq!(format!("{:>10}", l), "     1.0 m"); // Fails: padding is not added
}
```

The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#fillalignment) are explicit about this lack of global support:

> Note that alignment might not be implemented by some types. In particular, it is not generally implemented for the Debug trait. A good way to ensure padding is applied is to format your input, then pad this resulting string to obtain your output:
>
> ```
> println!("Hello {:^15}!", format!("{:?}", Some("hi"))); // => "Hello   Some("hi")   !"
> ```

But this workaround would have to be used in every place where a `Length` is being formatted. I don't want that.

Of course I can implement it all by hand, but there must be a better way.

I tried this naive way to reuse the `Display` features of `String`:

```
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", format!("{:.1} m", self.0))
    }
```

But of course it doesn't work, because the format string `"{}"` throws away all information that comes in through `f`.

Comment: Just curious, is this affected somehow by [this (pretty new) issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97797)?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A alternative solution is to use the numbers built-in `Display` implementation:

```rs
impl std::fmt::Display for Length {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        // The implementation of format of usize takes care of padding and alignment.
        self.0.fmt(f).and_then(
            // write our own results afterwards if the other format succeeded
            |_|write!(f," m"))
    }
}
```

[Proof in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ad123c0a474c73f2b20d07fe6aa713f)

Answer (score 1):

[`Formatter::pad`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.pad) to the rescue!

```
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        f.pad(&format!("{:.1} m", self.0))
    }
```

Besides width, fill and align, it also takes precision into account.

The only drawback is that it allocates a `String`, but I'm not sure there is a way around that.

Comment: Couldn't you kick the allocation can down the road a bit by writing multiple `&str` instead of one `&String`?

Comment: @MeetTitan Feel free to write up an answer demonstrating how :)