# Formatting a struct which implements fmt::Display doesn't respect format specifiers

Tags: rust

I have this example code.

```
use std::fmt;

struct MyStruct {
    mystring: String
}

impl fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "^.^ My String is *{}*. ^.^", self.mystring)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mystruct = MyStruct { mystring: "GOAT".to_string() };
    println!("|{:^80}|", mystruct);
    println!("|{:^80}|", "^.^ My String is *GOAT*. ^.^")
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2388521d41a50668fa45602db71757d2).)

I expect whatever is the output of the `MyStruct::fmt()` implementation, it will be written to a 80 character wide field, aligned to center, due to the `{:^80}` specifier. This is not what happens. The output doesn't respect the specifier, it's the same as if I simply wrote `{}`.

This is the output of my example:

```
|^.^ My String is *GOAT*. ^.^|
|                          ^.^ My String is *GOAT*. ^.^                          |
```

I'd expect these two lines to look identical.

How can I implement my formatter so that it respects the format specifier it is formatted with?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544241/how-to-implement-display-while-respecting-width-fill-and-alignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pad()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.pad) function respects formatting flags, however it expects a `&str` so you need to call `format!()`:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        f.pad(&format!("^.^ My String is *{}*. ^.^", self.mystring))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d3fe78544d7b820b4a4027f00ac1fa9).